# How to parse tumblr JSON feed

Tags: jquery, json, tumblr

I need to get the regular title and regular body from this JSON feed. I have tried various methods with little success. Anyone have a solution?

http://clintonbeattie.tumblr.com/bio/json

Thanks,
C

Comment: ur JSON: http://clintonbeattie.tumblr.com/api/read/json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not JSON, thats a weird-ish take on JSONP.

If you add a `<script />` tag with the `src` set to `http://clintonbeattie.tumblr.com/bio/json`, a global variable `tumblr_api_read` will point to an object with the response information;

```
var tumblr_api_read = {
    "tumblelog": {
        "title": "First Title",
        "description": "",
        "name": "clintonbeattie",
        "timezone": "US\/Eastern",
        "cname": false,
        "feeds": []
    },
    "posts": [{
        "id": null,
        "url": "",
        "url-with-slug": "",
        "type": "regular",
        "date-gmt": " GMT",
        "date": "Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00",
        "bookmarklet": null,
        "mobile": null,
        "feed-item": "",
        "from-feed-id": 0,
        "unix-timestamp": 1333622193,
        "format": "html",
        "reblog-key": "TmN3ujDJ",
        "slug": "",
        "regular-title": "",
        "regular-body": ""
    }]
};
```

Therefore do something like this;

```
<script src="http://clintonbeattie.tumblr.com/bio/json"></script>
<script>
    // Use tumblr_api_read.

    alert(tumblr_api_read.tumblelog.title); // Shows "First Title"

    for (var i=0;i<tumblr_api_read.posts.length;i++) {
        var thisPost = tumblr_api_read.posts[i];

        alert("This post was created at " + thisPost.date);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. The alert never happens. Checked the Resources in Chrome dev bar and states that get request was cancelled.

Comment: @Crashdesk: Meh, it seems the server returns a 404 if you the origin header is something they don't like... looking at the API, this doesn't seem to be a documented endpoint... where did you get this URL from? http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

Comment: I created a page called bio so thought I would use that URL to get the json because it isn't accessible through the normal procedure of http://clintonbeattie.tumblr.com/api/read/json. Readable in browser but not accessible as you say through a js call

Comment: Anyone know ho I can access data in the bio page?

Comment: @Crashdesk: You'll have to go through their API: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

Comment: Thanks guys. I have gone through it and there is no way to reference a page that is created. Shame. You have helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

From their [API docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api):

> JSON output
>
> By using /api/read/json instead of /api/read when calling the Read API, the output will be sent as JSON assigned to a Javascript variable named tumblr_api_read.

That ***is not*** JSON, or even JSONP. They are returning literal JavaScript. Thus, you have to follow their documentation and do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clintonbeattie.tumblr.com/api/read/json"></script>
```

This will create a global variable named `tumblr_api_read` (i.e. `window.tumblr_api_read`) that is an object literal.

Since you are using jQuery, you could do the following:

```
$.getScript("http://clintonbeattie.tumblr.com/api/read/json", function(script, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  console.log(window.tumblr_api_read.tumblelog.title);
});
```

It's amazing to me that these guys can link to [json.org](http://json.org/) in their documentation, yet screw it up this badly.

Comment: Thanks. It is really messed up and that's what's confusing me so much. I still can't find the feed for the bio page I have created though.

Comment: Read the docs [at the bottom](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1). Your pages doesn't show up as you can only get posts in JSON. You can however get the pages in XML: http://(YOU).tumblr.com/api/pages